# Can trigger function be called outside a trigger?

Tags: database, postgresql, security, triggers

We have a postgres DB. there we have a table A and a trigger.

The trigger triggers when a row is being inserted into table A. The trigger function will create a new table base on some fields in the triggered row.

Our problem: The user that add a row to table A does not have a permission to create tables to the schema.

For this matter we found the solution of adding `SECURITY DEFINER` in the end of our function declaration.

1. Is there better and safer way to do so?
2. Can the trigger function execute not from a trigger ? This way an abuser can call this method and explode our DB.
3. Is there a way to give a permission only to our trigger to run this function ?

Comment: A single table can have billions of records, do you really want so many tables? Without knowing all the details, this sounds like a risk to me. I would redesign my database to avoid dynamic table creation.

Comment: I've tried to simplify my problem. In our world we are using DB Partitions. Table A row id's will create a the partitioned table of table B. We have millions of records which updates frequently. So we went with this direction to split those tables to chunks.. Hope it clears a bit